# Google Docs: Don't change field name when expanding column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-docs

I can create a dynamic field in Google Docs like this: `=abs(A2*B7)`.
When expanding the column by pulling it down both fields get extended like this:
`=abs(A3*B8)`, `=abs(A4*B9)`, `=abs(A5*B10)`, ...

I only want one of the fields to get extended when pulling the column down.
Is there something like `=abs(A2*'B7)` to tell Docs not to touch the field?

Hope I could explain it somehow :)

Comment: Did you try the `$` this does the trick in excel

Comment: this `=abs(A2*$B7)`  is not working

Comment: Try `=abs(A2*B$7)`

Answer (score 1):

Posting the solution as an answer for workflow purposes. As [Björn B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61258256/google-docs-dont-change-field-name-when-expanding-column#comment108370238_61258256) said, to lock the Row 7 in B while > A2 increases it would be:

`=abs(A2*B$7)`

This is called an [Absolute Reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en) and these are some of the options:

- `$B$7` will lock both Column B and row 7
- `B$7` only the Row changes
- `$B7` only the Column changes